# QML ListView Scrolling

Tags: qml

On Android 4, when press-holding a key with accented characters like "i", a popup menu for the accented characters is displayed. Then sliding the finger into the button of any accented character within the popup menu highlights/selects the button, and finally releasing the finger, inputs the accented character into the target textbox.

I'd like to reproduce this (with a vertical popup menu) in QML with the addition of a scrolling behaviour when finger reaches the top or bottom of the popup menu (typical application: select a temperature among a hundred of values)

I tried to use a ListView for the popup menu, but the default scrolling behavior is not the one I need.
So far I managed to make a lame hack, using a Timer to update the ListView's contentY, but the code as well as the result look wrong. I was wondering if there is a proper way to achieve that.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for posting as an answer but dont have the 50 for commenting.

What do you mean with default scrolling behavior? Maybe the PathView is your answer, if I understood properly.

Further details will be appreciated